# infinite solution of a diophantine quadratic equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c,d$ be integers such that $GCD(a,b,c,d)=1$. Assume that the diophantine equation $ax^2+bxy+cxz+dyz-x=0$ has a non-zero solution.Can we assert that it admits infinitely many solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's all in the coefficient of $x$. When he is alone, then infinitely many solutions.  The solutions can be expressed using equations Pell.  The formula is rather long. Here not welcome a long formula and don't know if there is a point lead.

Comment: Individ. I am interested in a formula. Can you give one?

Comment: Below is a formula which proves that infinitely many solutions.  Formally, the task is already solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be integer and $f(x,y,z)=ax^2+bxy+cxz+dyz-x$.

Unless $b=1,d=0$ then $f(x,y,z)=0$ has infinitely many solutions via
the parametrization

$$X= -dk,Y=adk-ckb+ck+1,Z=k(b-1)$$ and $f(X,Y,Z)=0$.

If $b=1,d=0$ parametrization is $y=-ax-cz+1$ for integer $x,z$.

Comment: Funny! This answer is a joke probably?

Comment: @individ Can't you reproduce these are parametrizations?

Comment: This answer is useful. Is there infinite solution such that $x$ divdes $yz$?

Comment: @joaopa I think there is at for the first case. Substituting the parametrization, we must have $d$ divides expression depending on $k$. Solve it modulo $d$ and if it has solution, there will be infinitely many.

Comment: @joaopa Have in mind almost surely the first parametrization is _not complete_.

Comment: @joro. OK. No problem though.

Comment: For the equation.  $$ax^2+bxy+cxz+dyz-x=0$$  We will set the number  $p$ .  And then select $s$ so that the fraction was an integer.  And then Your formula can be written in General form.  $$x=-dp$$  $$y=cp+s$$  $$z=p(b+\frac{(bc-ad)p-1}{s})$$